# Memcached: auto-discovery python support on AWS Elasticache?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I started to use AWS Elasticache with my django web app.

I started by setting the cache location to the unique endpoint using the auto-discovery feature, but it doesn't seems to work.

I'm using pylibmc (1.2.2) and django-pylibmc-sasl (0.2.4) to connect to memcached from python.

Does the auto-discovery feature work on these clients? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 8):

## Quick answer

Yes for django: [django-elasticache](https://github.com/gusdan/django-elasticache)

### Long Answer

ElastiCache provides memcached interface so there are three solution of using it:

### 1. Memcached configured with location = Configuration Endpoint.

In this case your application
will randomly connect to nodes in cluster and cache will be used with not optimal
way. At some moment you will be connected to first node and set item. Minute later
you will be connected to another node and will not able to get this item.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache.gasdbp.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211',
    }
}
```

### 2. Memcached configured with all nodes.

It will work fine, memcache client will
 separate items between all nodes and will balance loading on client side. You will
 have problems only after adding new nodes or delete old nodes. In this case you should
 add new nodes manually and don't forget update your app after all changes on AWS.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            'cache.gqasdbp.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211',
            'cache.gqasdbp.0002.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211',
        ]
    }
}
```

### 3. Use django-elasticache.

It will connect to cluster and retrieve ip addresses
 of all nodes and configure memcached to use all nodes.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_elasticache.memcached.ElastiCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache-c.draaaf.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211',
    }
}
```

Difference between setup with nodes list (django-elasticache) and
connection to only one configuration Endpoint (using dns routing) you can see on
this graph:

[image: Get statistic for cluster with two node]

Comment: If you go to [django-elasticache](https://github.com/gusdan/django-elasticache) for installation instructions, do not use the command:

pip install django-pylibmc - it does not contain "django_elasticache" and will cause Internal Server Error. Use the command to install from Git instead.

Answer (score 1):

I used the PyLibMC binding which doesn't seems to support auto-discovery.

The Memcached backend built-in with Django and used in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#memcached) is working well with the unique endpoint provided by Elasticache.

Now everything's running fine and I improved a lot my response time with Memcached.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python client for aws elasticache, you can try it.

Installation:

```
pip install python_memcached hash_ring
pip install elasticache_pyclient
```

Simple usage:

```
>>> from elasticache_pyclient import MemcacheClient
>>> mc = MemcacheClient('test.lwgyhw.cfg.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211')
>>> mc.set('foo', 'bar')
True
>>> mc.get('foo')
'bar'
```

This package call python_memcached to do the actual memcache operation, so it has the exactly same functions as python_memcached, for more options, you can reference python_memcached.

Here is the elasticache_pyclient home page: 
https://github.com/yupeng820921/elasticache_pyclient

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.