# Is there a ElastiCache Cluster Client auto discovery for ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-elasticache

Is there an auto discovery client implemented/present for Ruby ?

Amazon's ElasticCache AutoDiscovery PHP client was released in Jan 3, 2013.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.html

Similar question for Python - [Memcached: auto-discovery python support on AWS Elasticache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612632/memcached-auto-discovery-python-support-on-aws-elasticache)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [dalli-elasticache](https://github.com/ktheory/dalli-elasticache).