# Is there a Python Memcached library with support for AWS ElastiCache's auto-discovery feature?

Tags: python, memcached, amazon-elasticache

Recently, AWS announced ElastiCache's auto-discovery feature, although they only officially released a client for Java. Does anyone know of a Python Memcached library with support for this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, ElastiCache cluster is just a bunch of memcached servers, so you need to give your memcached client the list of all of your servers and have the client do the relevant load balancing.

For Python, you have a couple of options:

- pylibmc - which is a wrapper around libmemcached - one of the best and fastest memcached clients there is
- python-memcached - a native Python client - very basic, but easy to work with, install and use

They haven't provided a client yet in python to deal with the new auto-discovery feature unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is library for django: [django-elasticache](https://github.com/gusdan/django-elasticache).

You can find more details in my answer on same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107561/1120528).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package, it can do elasticache auto discovery:
https://github.com/yupeng820921/elasticache_pyclient

Answer (score 0):

Yes [elasticache_pyclient](https://pypi.org/project/elasticache_pyclient/) supports aws elasticache auto discovery.

It uses python-memcached implements memcache command, and use hash_ring implements consistent hash.

```
# Usage (from documentation)
>>> from elasticache_pyclient import MemcacheClient
>>> mc = MemcacheClient('test.lwgyhw.cfg.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211')
>>> mc.set('foo', 'bar')
True
>>> mc.get('foo')
'bar'
```